# On Click of CSS Accordian Menu, page moves to top automatically

Tags: css

I have a simple HTML which has links and sub-links which uses below CSS. On Click of CSS Accordian Menu, page moves to top automatically.

Is it 'coz I have used target in css???

How to avoid this????

```
.accordion,
.accordion ul,
.accordion li,
.accordion a,
.accordion span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.accordion li {
    list-style: none;
}

.accordion li > a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 110px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 40px;

    color: #fdfdfd;
    font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);

    background: #6c6e74;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.accordion li > a span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #404247;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.accordion > li > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 4px 8px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.accordion li.files > a:before { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.accordion li.files:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.files:target > a:before { background-position: 0px -24px; }

.accordion li.mail > a:before { background-position: -24px 0px; }
.accordion li.mail:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.mail:target > a:before { background-position: -24px -24px; }

.accordion li.cloud > a:before { background-position: -48px 0px; }
.accordion li.cloud:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.cloud:target > a:before { background-position: -48px -24px; }

.accordion li.sign > a:before { background-position: -72px 0px; }
.accordion li.sign:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.sign:target > a:before { background-position: -72px -24px; }

.sub-menu li a {
    color: #797979;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

    background: #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.sub-menu li:last-child a { border: none; }

.sub-menu li > a span {
    color: #797979;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.sub-menu em {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 14px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.accordion > li:hover > a,
.accordion > li:target > a {
    color: #3e5706;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

    /*background: url(../img/active.png) repeat-x;*/
    background: #a5cd4e;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
}

.accordion > li:hover > a span,
.accordion > li:target > a span {
    color: #fdfdfd;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);
    background: #3e5706;
}

.accordion li > .sub-menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion li:target > .sub-menu {`enter code here`
    height: auto;
}
```

PLease help me in resolving this

Comment: Do your links have `href="#"`? This will cause the page to jump to the top.

Comment: can you please post your html?

Comment: `event.preventdefault()`

Comment: please share your code through jsfiddle or codepen for better understanding of the issue.